# mutationObserver срабатывает только после закрытия попап

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, tampermonkey

Хочу с помощью темперманки написать простой скрипт для [сайта](https://www.pes.spb.ru/services/acceptance_of_payments/payment_online/zhkh/), чтобы в форме ввода лицевого счета, номер счета подставлялся автоматически. Но на загрузке страницы дом элемент недоступен. Он появляется только после нажатия по ссылке.

Я написал mutationObserver

```js
    let input = document.querySelector('.ng-pristine');
    let link = document.querySelector('.clients-menu-item').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    let targetNode = document.body;
    const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

    const callback = async (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {

    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        console.log(mutation);
//        document.querySelector('.ng-pristine').value = 888888888;
        observer.disconnect();
    } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      //console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
    }
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations

link.addEventListener('click', () => {
   observer.observe(targetNode, config);

});
```

Ожидаемое поведение: на странице происходит клик по желаемой ссылке, происходит добавление дом элемента, открывается форма, скрипт её находит и срабатывает, подставляя значение в форму.

Фактическое поведение: на странице происходит клик по желаемой ссылке, происходит добавление дом элемента, открывается форма, скрипт срабатывает только после закрытия формы.

Как исправить?

Comment: Ты не можешь получить доступ к содержимому `iframe` политика безопасности `cors`.. По этому `document.querySelector('.ng-pristine')` будет `null` т.к. его нет в `document`.

Comment: да, я только хотел это отписать. Но интересно, что если я сделаю ПКМ по форме на самой странице, то в дом дереве браузера я могу увидеть этот элемент и менять его через консоль в инспекторе.

Comment: Потому что он выделен в инспекторе в DOM попробуй выделить в DOM то что выше iframe и он снова станет null в консоли..

Comment: окей, спасибо ра разъяснения.

Answer (score 0):

Форма является айфреймом из другого сетевого источника, потому по политике безопасности корс я не могу к нему получить доступ.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/818812)

Comment: Это и есть ответ, это не дополнение.